# Enable ssh-key-only login to my Mac for 1 user

Tags: ssh, macos, firewall

I have a Macbook Air that I would like to allow remote SSH access to without a password. I have created a user called `remotepair` that I have logged into and verified I can use the Mac with. I have also added this user to the "Remote Login" service's allowed user list and turned on the service. This was all done in the "Sharing" control panel.

I have gotten the public key of another computer and added it to the file `/Users/remotepair/.ssh/authorized_keys`. When the other computer attempts `ssh remotepair@<my ip>` I still get a password prompt.

How do I disable this password prompt?

Comment: I recommend adding "SSH Key-only authentication" to your question title--the way it reads now sounds like a regular GUI loginwindow login.

Comment: For curious people https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To disable password authentication you need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. In `Terminal`:

```
sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

(or replace with your favourite editor)

Look for the line:

```
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

And change it to:

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

That is, remove the `#` at the beginning, and change `yes` to `no`.

All subsequent ssh logins will now *REQUIRE* you to use an ssh key and will not prompt for a password. Ensure your ssh key works before doing this if you have no local access! There's no need to restart the ssh daemon or anything because it is started on demand for each new incoming connection. Note that you may also see a `PasswordAuthentication` line, but that defaults to `no` already.

If your ssh keys aren't working then that's a separate issue really, but this answers the question as it is posed now :)

Comment: I also need to add the user to the AllowUser setting. I can only guess the GUI setup didn't also modify this text line.

Comment: Note, in later versions of Mac OS X (definitely in El Capitan), sshd_config has been moved to `/etc/ssh/`.

Comment: Note, as of MacOS Sierra (v10.12.x), the default for `PasswordAuthentication` has changed to `yes`, so be sure to change it to `no`.

Comment: @TravisClarke Can confirm for 10.15 (Catalina). So this remains a requirement.

Answer (score 4):

To update the answer for macOS Sierra (10.12.6 specifically),
it appears the config file is now `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

2 lines must be uncommented+modified to fully disable password authentication: (These are lines 57 through 62, inclusive, in the default `sshd_config` file)

```
# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

As mentioned before, you may enable/disable ssh access from the System Preferences.app GUI, and no restart of the daemon is required between editing the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the permissions of the directories involved: `/Users/remotepair/` and `/Users/remotepair/.ssh`, they must not allow write access by "other" users. My `.ssh` has access rights only for the owner.

Also, on the remote system, do a `ssh -v remotepair@yoursystem` to see which authorization methods are allowed and attempted. Lookout for  `Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive`. Maybe you must enable `RSAAuthentication` on your system.

Answer (score 2):

On a test system here, disabling the SSH prompt required the following two lines to be added to `/etc/sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

The comments in `sshd_config` also advise the following line be added:

```
UsePAM no
```